# Angular 2 dynamic form binding won't work

Tags: angular

I'm creating a dynamic form with Angular 2 (or 4) with a form array (rooms) nesting a form array (children).

The children array won't bind controls and values in `.value` form property even if they are added to it.

Here the plunkr: https://embed.plnkr.co/DjtLLt0vS0qmmvgqKhN8/

What I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one simple error, remove the last `controls` from your `addChild()`:

```ts
addChild(i: number) {
    const control = 
       //remove the last 'controls'
       this.searchform.controls.rooms).controls[i]).controls["children"].controls;
    control.push(this.initAge());
}
```

and instead:

```ts
addChild(i: number) {
    const control =
      this.searchform.controls.rooms).controls[i]).controls["children"];
    control.push(this.initAge());
}
```

Here's your forked plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/SmnjBroGHufori1PWNSR?p=preview